# Problem with the carousel on Bootstrap v4.5.0

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have an issue with my carrousel on the latests version of bootstrap (4.5).
I'm using a multiple item carrousel by creating a grid inside (my item looks like that:

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="col-6" src="images/IMAGE 1" alt="">
        <img class="col-6" src="images/IMAGE 2" alt="">
</div>
```

To make it work on Bootstrap 4.5 I had to add this in my CSS:

```
.carousel-item { 
margin-right: 0;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

However the animation is still broken. Here's a video link, it's gonna be easier to understand: https://streamable.com/w3pt0j

Anyone knows how to fix this? I'm pretty sure it's something pretty obvious, but I'm still a beginner in HTML/CSS

Here's the link of the page: http://mathieucheve.fr/new/index.html

Comment: Could you share more of your HTML please?

Comment: @YoannPicquenot Added the link at the end of the post

Comment: It is your `margin-right: 0;` that is messing up the carousel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `margin-right` property in `.carousel-item` and it shall work as expected.

```
.carousel-item { 
/*margin-right: 0; */ /*Remove this line */
-webkit-box-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Oh well that was super easy… Thank you ! By the way, do you know why grid inside carousel no longer work properly on Bootstrap 4.5 ? (I was on 4.1.x before)

Comment: Sorry, I have not knowledge on grid inside the carousel. Can't help.